# What does the writing on Poe Dameron's flight vest say?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

Not the most vital fact, I know, but what does the writing on Poe's vest-thingy say?
[image: Poe Dameron wearing his flight suit]

Answer (score 70, accepted):

It's clearly in Aurebesh, so we're going to need a translation table<sup>1</sup>:

[image]

Now, what's tricky is that the text is upside-down, so we have to do a bit more detective work. Here's a pretty high-res shot of Poe's chest (linked to the right-side-up version):

[image]

From this, we can work out that the first word is "PULL", and that the bottom word starts "INFLA"

Now we have another image:

[image]

Where we can make out the "TO", and just enough to confirm that the last word ends with "AT", and then one more letter I can't quite make out. I'm going to make an educated guess that the last letter is an "E"

Which leaves us with:

> PULL TO INFLATE

Kind of anti-climactic, really.

---

<sup>1</sup> Taken from the back of a *Star Wars: Rebels* [identification card](http://a.dolimg.com/en-US/dxd/media/starwarsrebels/SWR_Ghost_Crew_ID_card.pdf) (PDF link)

Comment: The real question is why the one to one english character translation? Why not just make the text gibberish and not reveal what it says instead of going with classic junior high obfuscation?

Comment: @KaiQing Mildly humorous easter egg for fans who feel the need to translate the text? Plus it provides a canon reference for that vest being an actual lifevest, which adds that tiny bit of extra depth to the world.

Comment: 2 of your images are upside down.

Comment: @TylerH The images are upside down because the text is upside down. By flipping the images, the text is now right-side up. That is explained in the answer...

Comment: **Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35256/discussion-on-answer-by-jason-baker-what-does-the-writing-on-poe-damerons-fligh).** I left all the comments that were actually useful and relevant to the answer. If you feel any comments were deleted that shouldn't have been, **please ping me** and I can undelete them.

Comment: @randal'thor - I'm saving a screenshot of this so I can continually reference it when you become drunk with power.

Comment: @Richard I don't intend to become drunk with power. It may help that I'm never drunk with alcohol either ;-)